# Uploading a nextjs app to aws amplify has an error in build phase

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

```
2021-06-24T08:24:16.127Z [INFO]: # Cloning repository: git@github.com:Friel909/rivgurufrontend.git
2021-06-24T08:24:16.136Z [INFO]: Agent pid 134
2021-06-24T08:24:16.171Z [INFO]: Identity added: /root/.ssh/git_rsa (/root/.ssh/git_rsa)
2021-06-24T08:24:16.457Z [INFO]: Cloning into 'rivgurufrontend'...
2021-06-24T08:24:16.730Z [INFO]: Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.113.3' to the list of known hosts.
2021-06-24T08:24:20.145Z [INFO]: # Checking for Git submodules at: /codebuild/output/src574159690/src/rivgurufrontend/.gitmodules
2021-06-24T08:24:20.297Z [WARNING]: !Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src574159690/src/rivgurufrontend/amplify.yml'
2021-06-24T08:24:20.321Z [INFO]: # Retrieving environment cache...
2021-06-24T08:24:20.360Z [INFO]: # Retrieved environment cache
2021-06-24T08:24:20.421Z [INFO]: # Ensuring NPM package '@aws-amplify/cli' is version: 'latest'
2021-06-24T08:24:25.612Z [INFO]: # Patching NPM package '@aws-amplify/cli' from 4.29.4 to 5.0.1...
2021-06-24T08:25:09.935Z [INFO]: # Done patching NPM package '@aws-amplify/cli'
2021-06-24T08:25:17.255Z [INFO]: ## Starting Backend Build
                                 # Starting phase: build
2021-06-24T08:25:27.011Z [INFO]: [0mAmplify AppID found: dmnxn1mt5e02o. Amplify App name is: newAWSSite[0m
2021-06-24T08:25:27.072Z [INFO]: [0mBackend environment dev found in Amplify Console app: newAWSSite[0m
2021-06-24T08:25:27.859Z [WARNING]: - Fetching updates to backend environment: dev from the cloud.
2021-06-24T08:25:28.063Z [WARNING]: ✔ Successfully pulled backend environment dev from the cloud.
2021-06-24T08:25:28.067Z [INFO]: 
2021-06-24T08:25:30.999Z [INFO]: [33mNote: It is recommended to run this command from the root of your app directory[39m
2021-06-24T08:25:35.904Z [WARNING]: - Initializing your environment: dev
2021-06-24T08:25:36.155Z [WARNING]: ✔ Initialized provider successfully.
2021-06-24T08:25:36.435Z [WARNING]: - Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...
2021-06-24T08:25:42.065Z [INFO]: 
2021-06-24T08:25:42.067Z [INFO]: UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS amplify-newawssite-dev-151151 AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Thu Jun 24 2021 08:25:36 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) User Initiated
                                 UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS UnauthRole                    AWS::IAM::Role             Thu Jun 24 2021 08:25:41 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
                                 UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS AuthRole                      AWS::IAM::Role             Thu Jun 24 2021 08:25:41 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
                                 UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS DeploymentBucket              AWS::S3::Bucket            Thu Jun 24 2021 08:25:41 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
2021-06-24T08:25:57.046Z [INFO]: 
2021-06-24T08:25:57.047Z [INFO]: UPDATE_COMPLETE UnauthRole AWS::IAM::Role Thu Jun 24 2021 08:25:53 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
                                 UPDATE_COMPLETE AuthRole   AWS::IAM::Role Thu Jun 24 2021 08:25:54 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
2021-06-24T08:26:07.060Z [INFO]: 
2021-06-24T08:26:07.062Z [INFO]: UPDATE_COMPLETE                     DeploymentBucket              AWS::S3::Bucket            Thu Jun 24 2021 08:26:02 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
                                 UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS amplify-newawssite-dev-151151 AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Thu Jun 24 2021 08:26:04 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
                                 UPDATE_COMPLETE                     amplify-newawssite-dev-151151 AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Thu Jun 24 2021 08:26:05 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
2021-06-24T08:26:07.244Z [WARNING]: - Uploading files...
2021-06-24T08:26:07.303Z [WARNING]: - Uploading files...
2021-06-24T08:26:07.363Z [WARNING]: - Uploading files...
2021-06-24T08:26:07.414Z [WARNING]: ✔ All resources are updated in the cloud
2021-06-24T08:26:07.415Z [INFO]: 
2021-06-24T08:26:07.415Z [INFO]: 
2021-06-24T08:26:07.952Z [INFO]: [32mInitialized your environment successfully.[39m
2021-06-24T08:26:07.953Z [INFO]: [32mYour project has been successfully initialized and connected to the cloud![39m
                                 [32mSome next steps:[39m
                                 [0m"amplify status" will show you what you've added already and if it's locally configured or deployed[0m
                                 [0m"amplify add <category>" will allow you to add features like user login or a backend API[0m
                                 [0m"amplify push" will build all your local backend resources and provision it in the cloud[0m
                                 [0m"amplify console" to open the Amplify Console and view your project status[0m
                                 [0m"amplify publish" will build all your local backend and frontend resources (if you have hosting category added) and provision it in the cloud[0m
                                 [32mPro tip:[39m
                                 [0mTry "amplify add api" to create a backend API and then "amplify publish" to deploy everything[0m
2021-06-24T08:26:10.356Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: build
                                 ## Completed Backend Build
                                 ## Starting Frontend Build
2021-06-24T08:26:10.358Z [INFO]: # Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: npm ci
2021-06-24T08:26:18.115Z [INFO]: > core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /codebuild/output/src574159690/src/rivgurufrontend/node_modules/core-js
                                 > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
2021-06-24T08:26:18.326Z [INFO]: > ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /codebuild/output/src574159690/src/rivgurufrontend/node_modules/ejs
                                 > node ./postinstall.js
2021-06-24T08:26:18.361Z [INFO]: Thank you for installing [35mEJS[0m: built with the [32mJake[0m JavaScript build tool ([32mhttps://jakejs.com/[0m)
2021-06-24T08:26:18.533Z [INFO]: > bcrypt@5.0.1 install /codebuild/output/src574159690/src/rivgurufrontend/node_modules/bcrypt
                                 > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
2021-06-24T08:26:18.689Z [INFO]: [bcrypt] Success: "/codebuild/output/src574159690/src/rivgurufrontend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node" is installed via remote
2021-06-24T08:26:18.706Z [INFO]: added 946 packages in 8.038s
2021-06-24T08:26:18.716Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
                                 # Starting phase: build
2021-06-24T08:26:18.717Z [INFO]: # Executing command: npm run build
2021-06-24T08:26:18.882Z [INFO]: > edemy@1.5.0 build /codebuild/output/src574159690/src/rivgurufrontend
                                 > next build
2021-06-24T08:26:19.813Z [INFO]: info  - Using webpack 4. Reason: custom webpack configuration in next.config.js https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
2021-06-24T08:26:20.355Z [INFO]: Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
2021-06-24T08:26:20.356Z [INFO]: This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
                                 You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
                                 https://nextjs.org/telemetry
2021-06-24T08:26:20.385Z [INFO]: info  - Checking validity of types...
2021-06-24T08:26:20.391Z [INFO]: info  - Creating an optimized production build...
2021-06-24T08:26:20.428Z [INFO]: > [PWA] Compile client (static)
2021-06-24T08:26:20.428Z [INFO]: > [PWA] Auto register service worker with: /codebuild/output/src574159690/src/rivgurufrontend/node_modules/next-pwa/register.js
                                 > [PWA] Service worker: /codebuild/output/src574159690/src/rivgurufrontend/.next/sw.js
                                 > [PWA]   url: /sw.js
                                 > [PWA]   scope: /
2021-06-24T08:26:20.698Z [INFO]: > [PWA] Compile server
2021-06-24T08:26:53.998Z [WARNING]: @rollup/plugin-replace: 'preventAssignment' currently defaults to false. It is recommended to set this option to `true`, as the next major version will default this option to `true`.
2021-06-24T08:26:57.000Z [INFO]: info  - Compiled successfully
2021-06-24T08:26:57.000Z [INFO]: info  - Collecting page data...
2021-06-24T08:26:57.615Z [WARNING]: Warning: You have opted-out of Automatic Static Optimization due to `getInitialProps` in `pages/_app`. This does not opt-out pages with `getStaticProps`
2021-06-24T08:26:57.616Z [WARNING]: Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/opt-out-auto-static-optimization
2021-06-24T08:26:57.626Z [INFO]: info  - Generating static pages (0/1)
2021-06-24T08:26:57.866Z [INFO]: info  - Generating static pages (1/1)
2021-06-24T08:26:57.867Z [INFO]: info  - Finalizing page optimization...
2021-06-24T08:26:57.870Z [INFO]: 
2021-06-24T08:26:57.891Z [INFO]: Page                                                           Size     First Load JS
                                 ┌ λ /                                                          4.17 kB         145 kB
                                 ├   /_app                                                      0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /404                                                       1.87 kB         109 kB
                                 ├ λ /about-1                                                   3.7 kB          121 kB
                                 ├ λ /about-2                                                   2.62 kB         120 kB
                                 ├ λ /about-3                                                   6.27 kB         119 kB
                                 ├ λ /admin/dashboard                                           2.79 kB         110 kB
                                 ├ λ /admin/pending-requests                                    2.08 kB         109 kB
                                 ├ λ /advisor                                                   2.53 kB         109 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/contact                                               0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/apply/approve-requests                             0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/apply/decline-requests                             0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/apply/pending-requests                             0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/auth/account                                       0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/auth/confirm-email                                 0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/auth/forgot-password                               0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/auth/password-change                               0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/auth/signin                                        0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/auth/signup                                        0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/courses                                            0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/courses/[id]                                       0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/courses/checkout                                   0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/courses/course/[id]                                0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/courses/course/new                                 0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/courses/course/remove                              0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/courses/course/update                              0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/courses/course/video-upload                        0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/courses/enrolled                                   0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/courses/enrolled/[id]                              0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/courses/enrolled/videos                            0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/courses/homepage-courses                           0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/courses/my-courses                                 0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/courses/search                                     0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /api/v1/user/apply                                         0 B             107 kB
                                 ├ λ /authentication                                            5.41 kB         120 kB
                                 ├ λ /become-a-teacher                                          3.76 kB         128 kB
                                 ├ λ /blog-1                                                    2.57 kB         109 kB
                                 ├ λ /blog-2                                                    2.71 kB         110 kB
                                 ├ λ /blog-3                                                    2.69 kB         110 kB
                                 ├ λ /blog-4                                                    3.55 kB         113 kB
                                 ├ λ /cart                                                      2.58 kB         109 kB
                                 ├ λ /categories                                                2.65 kB         110 kB
                                 ├ λ /checkout                                                  3.07 kB         110 kB
                                 ├ λ /coming-soon                                               2.89 kB         110 kB
                                 ├ λ /contact                                                   4.69 kB         138 kB
                                 ├ λ /courses                                                   1.7 kB          109 kB
                                 ├ λ /courses-1                                                 1.36 kB         108 kB
                                 ├ λ /courses-2                                                 3.08 kB         110 kB
                                 ├ λ /courses-3                                                 4.87 kB         112 kB
                                 ├ λ /courses-4                                                 2.84 kB         110 kB
                                 ├ λ /courses-5                                                 2.99 kB         110 kB
                                 ├ λ /courses-6                                                 3.39 kB         110 kB
                                 ├ λ /courses/[id]                                              9.15 kB         123 kB
                                 ├ λ /courses/search                                            1.75 kB         109 kB
                                 ├ λ /distance-learning                                         6.17 kB         116 kB
                                 ├ λ /elearning                                                 7.02 kB         120 kB
                                 ├ λ /events                                                    2.82 kB         110 kB
                                 ├ λ /faq                                                       6.94 kB         117 kB
                                 ├ λ /gallery                                                   16 kB           123 kB
                                 ├ λ /health-coaching                                           5.63 kB         115 kB
                                 ├ λ /kindergaten                                               5.41 kB         115 kB
                                 ├ λ /language-school                                           5.09 kB         115 kB
                                 ├ λ /membership-levels                                         2.67 kB         110 kB
                                 ├ λ /modern-schooling                                          1.68 kB         142 kB
                                 ├ λ /my-courses                                                3.6 kB          110 kB
                                 ├ λ /my-courses/view/[id]                                      3.96 kB         111 kB
                                 ├ λ /online-training                                           4.83 kB         122 kB
                                 ├ λ /privacy-policy                                            3.95 kB         111 kB
                                 ├ λ /products-list-1                                           2.67 kB         110 kB
                                 ├ λ /products-list-2                                           3.18 kB         110 kB
                                 ├ λ /profile                                                   3.63 kB         111 kB
                                 ├ λ /purchase-guide                                            4.2 kB          111 kB
                                 ├ λ /regist                                                    47.2 kB         154 kB
                                 ├ λ /single-blog-1                                             2.73 kB         112 kB
                                 ├ λ /single-blog-2                                             2.8 kB          112 kB
                                 ├ λ /single-blog-3                                             3.36 kB         115 kB
                                 ├ λ /single-courses-1                                          6.69 kB         120 kB
                                 ├ λ /single-courses-2                                          5.45 kB         112 kB
                                 ├ λ /single-events                                             4.07 kB         114 kB
                                 ├ λ /single-products                                           4.39 kB         114 kB
                                 ├ λ /success-story                                             5.77 kB         116 kB
                                 ├ λ /teacher/course/[id]                                       7.42 kB         114 kB
                                 ├ λ /teacher/course/create                                     6.58 kB         113 kB
                                 ├ λ /teacher/course/upload-course-video                        4.99 kB         119 kB
                                 ├ λ /teacher/courses                                           4.43 kB         111 kB
                                 ├ λ /teacher/courses/course-edit                               4.11 kB         111 kB
                                 ├ λ /teacher/dashboard                                         2.85 kB         110 kB
                                 ├ λ /terms-of-service                                          3.98 kB         111 kB
                                 ├ λ /user/edit-password                                        2.01 kB         109 kB
                                 ├ λ /user/edit-profile                                         2.02 kB         109 kB
                                 ├ λ /user/my-profile                                           2.05 kB         109 kB
                                 ├ λ /vendor-certification                                      8.07 kB         121 kB
                                 └ λ /yoga-training                                             7.59 kB         121 kB
                                 + First Load JS shared by all                                  107 kB
                                 ├ chunks/11bc2bf37049d64376b67555cfd11e8f5753fb99.f1bb36.js  6.87 kB
                                 ├ chunks/c6464ce45454a8a567d341c8d3b5fce3b9953bc5.e565f0.js  5.11 kB
                                 ├ chunks/ca92af84a5277c2d4f7907f2d3fdddd999dec0ab.a92b9c.js  18.2 kB
                                 ├ chunks/commons.f56827.js                                   13.3 kB
                                 ├ chunks/framework.3105c3.js                                 42.3 kB
                                 ├ chunks/main.19746a.js                                      9.09 kB
                                 ├ chunks/pages/_app.6bbed9.js                                10.8 kB
                                 ├ chunks/webpack.0e2ed6.js                                   1.19 kB
                                 └ css/6355be800e5cb2e052ca.css                               87.8 kB
                                 λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
                                 ○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
                                 ●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
                                 (ISR)     incremental static regeneration (uses revalidate in getStaticProps)
2021-06-24T08:26:58.028Z [INFO]: Starting SSR Build...
2021-06-24T08:27:50.600Z [ERROR]: Error: 'Command failed with exit code 1: node_modules/.bin/next build',
                                  command: 'node_modules/.bin/next build',
                                  exitCode: 1,
                                  signal: undefined,
                                  signalDescription: undefined,
                                  stdout: 'info  - Using webpack 4. Reason: custom webpack configuration in next.config.js https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5\n' +
                                  'info  - Checking validity of types...\n' +
                                  'info  - Creating an optimized production build...\n' +
                                  '> [PWA] Compile client (static)\n' +
                                  '> [PWA] Auto register service worker with: /codebuild/output/src574159690/src/rivgurufrontend/node_modules/next-pwa/register.js\n' +
                                  '> [PWA] Service worker: /codebuild/output/src574159690/src/rivgurufrontend/.next/sw.js\n' +
                                  '> [PWA]   url: /sw.js\n' +
                                  '> [PWA]   scope: /\n' +
                                  '> [PWA] Compile server',
                                  stderr: "@rollup/plugin-replace: 'preventAssignment' currently defaults to false. It is recommended to set this option to `true`, as the next major version will default this option to `true`.\n" +
                                  'Failed to compile.\n' +
                                  '\n' +
                                  "ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mock-aws-s3' in '/codebuild/output/src574159690/src/rivgurufrontend/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util'\n" +
                                  '\n' +
                                  '\n' +
                                  '> Build error occurred\n' +
                                  'Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors\n' +
                                  '    at /codebuild/output/src574159690/src/rivgurufrontend/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:17:924\n' +
                                  '    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n' +
                                  '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)\n' +
                                  '    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/codebuild/output/src574159690/src/rivgurufrontend/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:6:584)',
                                  failed: true,
                                  timedOut: false,
                                  isCanceled: false,
Terminating logging...
```

When I tried using ContinuousDeployment I chose github and fill in my github repo information. but then it shows this error on the build phase even thought when I try to build it locally with npm run build, it works okay.

I've tried using many methods including using the console to deploy it and using the amplify directly but both did not work.

Comment: did you end up solving it yet? I'm also stuck on this amplify build fail.